# Parser for a process algebra

Tags: java

i would like to create a parser for a process algebra. The process algebra has this syntax:

```
System=P:[s,l]|(P:[s,l']|P:[s,l])\{a,b}
```

How can i check if a string statement follows this syntax??? Some pseudo-code would be very helpful.

Comment: you could accomplish this with regular expressions pretty easily. This site has a lot of information about them: regular-expressions.info

Comment: Yes i know that regular expressions can help but i also have to create the syntax tree.i have to split the statement and give priority to some operators like that one "|" and i don't know if i have to use a stack?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use regular expressions to accomplish this task in the general case because you have nested constructs (parenthetical expressions). You need at least the power of what is called a "[push-down automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push-down_automaton)."

To solve this problem, you need what is called a "[parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)" that recognizes the grammar of the process language.

Do you have a grammar specification for the language? You could express the grammar with a tool like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Research the results of this Google search: [Java Parser Generators](http://www.google.com/search?q=java%20parser%20generators)

Comment: thanx for your answer. but if i try to implement it by my-own what would i do?
Like i see it i would split the string by the operators that the syntax gives me.

Comment: Writing a parser "from scratch" is a great exercise and can teach you a lot about how they work. Is this a homework question? If so, please tag it as such. Perhaps the most "straight-forward" way to write a parser is to write what is called a "recursive descent" parser. With this approach you basically traverse the string with a bunch of mutually recursive functions. Before parsing though, it's a good idea to break up the input characters into tokens, this is called "lexical analysis" and is the job of something called a "lexer."

Comment: thanx for your answer. but if i try to implement it by my-own what would i do?Like i see it i would split the string by the operators that the syntax gives me.  i tried to did the pseudo-code:
String solvePS(Population) {
     if (Population != <>) {
             if(Population has '(' and ')'){..}
             if (Population has '%') {....}
             else if (expr.contains("|")) {
                String []table=expr.split("|");
                 ....
               } else if (expr matches("[a-zA-Z]*:\\[[a-zA-Z]*,[a-zA-Z]*\\]")) {...
            }
        }

        return "";
    }

Comment: There a whole university level courses on this subject, so I can't answer it completely in a StackOverflow comment stream :) I'd encourage you to Google the terms that I've used and download the source code of systems that have parsers. Study those systems to understand the structure. But again, the basic idea is: character input stream is broken up into a token stream (many characters may comprise a single token), those tokens are matched against a grammar. The grammar may be encoded in a set of recursive functions. Those functions construct the syntax tree. Google "Purple Dragon Book."